# getting syntax error on creating function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a function like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TitleToFileName(title varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200)
  BEGIN
    set title = REPLACE(title,":"," ");
    set title=REPLACE(title,"/"," ");
    set title=REPLACE(title,"_"," ");
    RETURN title;
  END
```

MySQL shows error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

I tried using ' instead of " and @title instead of title , but didn't work..

Comment: Probably a delimiter problem.  Add `DELIMITER $$` or something similar before the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to redefine Delimiter to something else (eg: `$$`), instead of (`;`).
- Also as a safety measure, check if the same name function already exists or not (`DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS`)
- At the end, redefine the `DELIMITER` to `;`

Try :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `TitleToFileName`$$
CREATE FUNCTION TitleToFileName(title varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200)
  BEGIN
    set title = REPLACE(title,":"," ");
    set title=REPLACE(title,"/"," ");
    set title=REPLACE(title,"_"," ");
    RETURN title;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```