# How to use TIMEDIFF in a mysql function?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a mysql function that wraps a sequence of several mysql calculations. As starting point, I just tried to wrap simple `TIMEDIFF`, but this even fails:

```
CREATE FUNCTION diff_minutes(t1 TIME, t2 TIME) RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1, t2);
END;
```

Result:

> '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1, t2)' at line 3

Comment: Error is mostly likely due to some other issue here. You need to redefine `DELIMITER` from `;` to something else. Check this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557540/2469308

Comment: Could you go into detail why I have to redefine the delimiter here? Isn't there a simple solution without?

Comment: If you only have 1 statement in a stored program you don't need BEGIN and END block and you don't need to set delimiters, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @membersound it is explained in the [MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html): "*If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.*"

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it as below

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS diff_minutes $$   

CREATE FUNCTION diff_minutes(t1 TIME, t2 TIME)
RETURNS BIGINT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    RETURN(
       SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1, t2)
    );
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i8bh9iohJAQFKGDnUjA4pZ/1)

`READS SQL DATA` indicates that the function contains statements that read data (for example, `SELECT`), but not statements that write data. You could also debate here to use `NOT DETERMINISTIC` here instead as you are not really "reading" data here...

As explained in the manual [CREATE FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

> **Comment of P.Salmon (under the question)** 
>   If you only have 1 statement in a stored program you don't need BEGIN
>   and END block and you don't need to set delimiters,

very true, this is also possible.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS diff_minutes $$   

CREATE FUNCTION diff_minutes(t1 TIME, t2 TIME)
RETURNS BIGINT
READS SQL DATA
RETURN(
  SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1, t2)
);

DELIMITER ;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i8bh9iohJAQFKGDnUjA4pZ/2)

Comment: Maybe `DROP FUNCTION..` can be avoided if the function is not already created, and then redefining `DELIMITER` wont be required in the second query of your answer. Another possibility that I feel MySQL should add in newer versions is to have `CREATE [function | table | procedure ....] **IF NOT EXISTS** ..`

Comment: indeed @MadhurBhaiya when the `DROP FUNCTION` is not needed in the second query you dont have to use `DELIMITER`.. Yes  `CREATE [function | table | procedure ....] IF NOT EXISTS` syntax support would be great MySQL should ideally implement `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements for stored programs/view aswell..