# SQL query not working when I try to add it on a Event

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SET @rank = 0;
UPDATE t1 SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

and I want to create an Event that executes this query every x minutes but i keep getting this error:

> The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
>   EVENT `updaterank` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2019-09-17
>   00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SET @rank = 0; UPDATE
>   t1 SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1) ORDER BY balance DESC;" MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE t1 SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1) ORDER BY balance DESC'
>   at line 3

Comment: You probably need to redefine `DELIMTER` at the beginning from `;` to something else (eg: `$$`). Check this answer (for example): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557540/2469308

Comment: Tried like the example you showed but that doesn't seem to do it

Comment: Please post the complete query including `CREATE ...` parts that you are running to create the event.

Comment: That is the complete query

Answer (score 0):

When i look into the error it seams you are using backticks in your MySQL user account/hostname those should be single quoted like `'root'@'localhost'`. i would use `DEFINER = CURRENT_USER()` instead but sure to run it from the correct account..

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER() EVENT `updaterank`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2019-09-17 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
  SET 
   @rank = 0;
   UPDATE t1 SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1) ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eiS6RoU8n19K6fhTDRvcvL/0)

Or

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER() EVENT `updaterank`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2019-09-17 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
  UPDATE t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS init  SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1) ORDER BY balance DESC;
```